# Range function is not working properly in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```py
for i in range():
    for j in range(i):
        print("*",end = " ")
    print()
```

Error:

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-81-6bc40b03c32e> in <module>
----> 1 for i in range():
      2     for j in range(i):
      3         print("*",end = " ")
      4     print()
      5 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Python requires proper indentation to work correctly. Please format your code properly so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, `range()` is not valid, you need to provide an argument to allow it to create a range.

For example:

- `range(3)` will give you a generator for the integers `{ 0, 1, 2 }`;
- `range(3, 20, 7)` will generate `{ 3, 10, 17 }`;
- `range()` will just generate an error :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an `int`  parameter in `range()` just the way you did in the second for loop. like, `range(10)`.

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i):
        print("*",end = " ")
    print()
```